# Multi-dimensional Array; JavaScript; Algorithum

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

***Details***
I'm working on an algo dealing with a multi-dimensional array. If there is a zero, then the elements of the same column, but following arrays will also equal zero. I want to be able to sum the items that are not zeroed out.

```js
Example:

matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2],
          [0, 5, 0, 0], 
          [2, 0, 3, 3]] --->2, 3, and 3 will not be counted since there is a zero above it.

the output should be: 1+1+2+5 = 9
```

***My work so far***

```js
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
    console.log(matrix[i])
        for(var j=0;j<=matrix.length;j++){
            console.log(matrix[i][j])
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
                console.log(true)
//------------>Here is my problem
            }
            else {
                console.log(false)
            }
            if(matrix[i][j] !== 0){
                sum+=matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I wanted to use this:

```js
matrix[i+1][j] = 0;
```

but I get this error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Can someon help me understand why my thought process doesn't work and any suggestion to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: How you come up with `1+1+2+5 = 9`. Would you edit the answer and explain it? I mean what is your expected result and how?

Comment: `j<=matrix.length` does not make sense. Did you mean `j < matrix[i].length`?

Comment: When looping over array indexes, the condition should be `index < array.length`, not `index <= array.length`

Comment: You can't do `matrix[i+1][j] = 0;` when you're on the last row. So check if `i == matrix.length - 1` before doing that.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Ah, yes, that makes sense!

Comment: @Barmar Understood on the first comment. Leftover from a different angle I was working. Second comment, Where would you implement it?

Comment: Maybe `if (i < matrix.length - 1) {matrix[i+1][j] = 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the matrix during the algorithm, then one solution is to have flags that indicate for each column whether or not you have already encountered a 0 in that column:

```js
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    let sum = 0;
    let flags = Array(matrix[0].length).fill(true);
    for (let row of matrix) {
        for (let j = 0; j < flags.length; j++) {
            if (flags[j] &&= row[j]) sum += row[j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

let matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
              [0, 5, 0, 0], 
              [2, 0, 3, 3]];
console.log(matrixElementsSum(matrix));
```

Note that your loop on `j` should have as condition `j < matrix[0].length`

If your IDE complains about the assignment in the `if` condition, then you can opt to split the assignment from the condition:

```
flags[j] &&= row[j];
if (flags[j]) sum += row[j];
```

Or, if you have no support for this operator:

```
flags[j] = flags[j] && row[j];
if (flags[j]) sum += row[j];
```

Comment: When I run this in my VS Code, it doesn't like the if statement?

Comment: Maybe because it wants to warn about an assignment that happens with an expression, but it is intended here. You can choose to first do the assignment, and then the evaluation if you like.

Comment: Ok, I had something else going on in my VS code with a setting. I changed that and retried what you had originally and it worked BUT the answer comes out as 7 and not 9!

Comment: Then you have something different. You can run the snippet in my answer and see it outputs 9

Comment: I see that it works in the snippett! Just curious as to why VS code is not liking it. I did forget to mention that I had to take away one & to make it run. Otherwise, it throws the error I mentioned before. But from what I see, this should be working.

Comment: Of course, it won't work with one `&`: that is a different operator! See addition to answer....

Comment: BINGO! That last edit did the trick! So I have no support for the operator. I'm not sure I entirely understand but now that I have this working, I'll be able to break it down. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Working with rows in a matrix with Javascript is usually much easier than working with columns.  So one clean way of writing this is to first transpose the matrix (flipping it over the northwest-southeast diagonal) and then summing each row until you hit a zero, finally summing those results.

```
[
  [ 0, 0, 5 ], // => 0     = 0
  [ 1, 5, 0 ], // => 1 + 5 = 6
  [ 1, 0, 3 ], // => 1     = 1
  [ 2, 0, 3 ], // => 2     = 2
]              //          +__
//                           9
```

`transpose` and `sum` functions are quite easily (and might well be stored in one's personal utility library, as they are likely to get reused.

We also need a `sumToFirstZero` function.  Here we write a recursive one that manages to bury a little complexity since `n ?` distinguishes from everything else our two base cases - when we've completed the row and therefore `n` is `undefined`, and when `n` is zero.  In either of those cases, we simply return `0`.  In other cases, we add the current value to a recursive call on the remainder of the array.

The main function just puts these three together.

```js
const transpose = (xs) => 
  xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))
  
const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const sumToFirstZero = ([n, ...ns]) => 
  n ? n + sumToFirstZero (ns) : 0

const problem = (matrix) =>
  sum (transpose (matrix) .map (sumToFirstZero))

console .log (problem ([
  [0, 1, 1, 2], 
  [0, 5, 0, 0], 
  [2, 0, 3, 3]
]))
```

To make it clear how `sumToFirstZero` manages to bury a little complexity, this would be a more logically clear version of the same function:

```js
const sumToFirstZero = ([n, ...ns]) => 
  n == undefined 
    ? 0
  : n == 0
    ? 0
  : n + sumToFirstZero (ns)
```

But since `n` has to be a number or `undefined` if we bottom out on the recursion, we can take advantage of JS's boolean coercion with `(! n) ? 0 : n + sumToFirstZero (ns)`, or, as we do above with `n ? n + sumToFirstZero (ns) : 0`

Of course we don't *have* to do this on the (transposed) rows.  We could work directly on the columns, fiddling with array parameters.  But I find this much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```js
const mat1 = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]]
    
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {

  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      const row = matrix[i]
      for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
          if (matrix[i][j] === 0) {
              for (let k = i; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                  matrix[k][j] = 0
              }
          }
      }
  }

  let total = 0
  for (let i of matrix)
      for (let j of i)
          total += j;

  return total;
}

console.log(matrixElementsSum(mat1));
```

Comment: Please see [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)